# ImportError: cannot import name 'unique_everseen'

Tags: python, more-itertools

I'm trying to import quandl in to spyder (python 3.6) and I get the issues as seen in the title above. Could it be a fault with the more-itertools package, as I have not seen a file within the more_itertools folder which matches unique_everseen

```
File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-
packages\quandl\model\merged_dataset.py", line 1, in <module>
from more_itertools import unique_everseen
```

Comment: Have you installed `more_itertools`? (more specifically - have you made sure it's installed in the environment that your IDE is using?)

Comment: Yes I took the folder from github and placed it in the site-packages folder, do I need to do anything else with it?

Comment: Anaconda's environment, your system environment and any other virtual environment you may have put the package into will differ. Have a read of https://conda.io/docs/using/pkgs.html

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `pip` to install the package since `more_itertools` is not yet an official package on `conda`.  Activate the desired conda environment and install:

```
> activate <environment name>
> pip install more_itertools
```

See installation instructions [here](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)